# Docker - How do I pull/push multiple images at once?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, dockerhub

I have a project that contains 2 frontend app(React), 1 backend app (Node), mongodb and redis.

My project folder like this

```
_> client
   |_>  Dockerfile // Dockerfile for first react app
_> panel
   |_> Dockerfile // Dockerfile for seconde react app
_> mongo
   |_> Dockerfile // It contains initial datas for database
_> server
   |_> Dockerfile // Docker file for nodejs backend
_> docker-compose.yml
```

*There is also package.json and other folders under each project folder, but I did not go into detail.*

My docker-compose file like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  testproject-client:
    container_name: testproject-client
    build: ./client
    image: bk52/testproject-client:latest
    ports:
      - 9200:5173
    depends_on:
      - testproject-server
  testproject-panel:
    container_name: testproject-panel
    build: ./panel
    image: bk52/testproject-panel:latest
    ports:
      - 9400:5174
    depends_on:
      - testproject-server
  testproject-server:
    container_name: testproject-server
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: bk52/testproject-server:latest
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
    depends_on:
      - testproject-mongo
      - testproject-redis
  testproject-mongo:
    container_name: testproject-mongo
    build: ./mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: my_test_user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_test_password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: my-test-database
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    volumes:
      - testproject-data:/data/db
  testproject-redis:
    container_name: testproject-redis
    image: 'redis'
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
volumes:
  testproject-data:
```

The project runs successfully locally with docker-compose. For the project to run successfully, all components (mongo, redis, backend and two frontend app) must be installed.

I named the backend and frontend images and uploaded them to docker-hub.

- bk52/testproject-client:latest
- bk52/testproject-panel:latest
- bk52/testproject-server:latest

**When I pull these images from Docker Hub, Mongo and Redis do not load automatically. It does not create the table with initial data for Mongodb. Additionally, it does not perform the necessary volume and port mappings in docker-compose.**

Is there a method or approach where I can push this project to docker hub or pull it to another environment at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you pull Docker images from Docker Hub, it's important to note that the images themselves only contain the base installation of the respective software (MongoDB, Redis, etc.). If you need specific configurations, initial data, volume mappings, or port mappings, you'll have to set those up in your docker-compose.yml file or Docker run commands.add service as mango:latest....it will work.!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).